# Como debugar shell script no linux?

Tags: linux, shell-script

Eu sou novato com linux, e estou aprendendo shell script e minha dúvida é a seguinte.

Quando eu quero debugar algo em PHP por exemplo, eu coloco um **breakpoint** no código e rodo o mesmo com o debug ligado, eu queria seber como posso fazer isto com um shell script?
Teria como eu fazer o debug passando linha a linha do meu código? Obrigado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para fazer debug de Bash-Script existem algumas ferramentas muito úteis:

## Parametro `-n` no `bash`

O uso do comando `bash -n` faz a análise sintáxica do seu script, para verificar se existem erros de digitação ou que impessam seu script de ser executado.

Arquivo: exemploBashN.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Isso é um exemplo"
echo "Agora falta uma aspas
echo "E o bash -n deve notificar esse problema"
```

Execução:

```
$bash -n exemploBashN.sh
exemploBashN.sh: line 5: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
exemploBashN.sh: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file
$
```

## Comando `set`

O comando `set` permite habilitar e desabilitar algumas funcionalidades do `bash`. Quando usado com `-`, ele habilita a funcionalidade. Quando usando com `+` ele desliga a mesma.

### `set -x`

Ativa a impressão da EXPRESSÃO executada.

Arquivo: exemploBashSetX.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x
echo "Quantos anos você tem?"
read idade
echo "Você tem $idade anos"
set +x
echo "Agora sem imprimir a expressão executada"
```

Execução:

```
$./exemploSetX.sh
+ echo 'Quantos anos você tem?'
Quantos anos você tem?
+ read idade
26
+ echo 'Você tem 26 anos'
Você tem 26 anos
+ set +x
Agora sem imprimir a expressão executada
$
```

### `set -v`

Ativa a impressão da LINHA executada

Arquivo: exemploSetV.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -v
echo "Quantos anos você tem?"
read idade
echo "Você tem $idade anos"
set +x
echo "Agora sem imprimir a LINHA executada"
```

Execução:

```
$./exemploSetV.sh
echo "Quantos anos você tem?"
Quantos anos você tem?
read idade
26
echo "Você tem $idade anos"
Você tem 26 anos
set +v
Agora sem imprimir a LINHA executada
$
```

### `set -e`

Aborta a execução do script quando qualquer comando falhar.

Arquivo: exemploSetE.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo "Carregando www.goooooooogle.com.br (site não existe)"

curl -v -f "www.goooooooogle.com.br" > site.html

echo "Essas linha não serão executadas"
echo "pois o comando 'curl' não conseguiu executar com sucesso"   

set +e

echo "Nem essas, pois o script já foi abortado."
```

Execução:

```
./exemploSetE.sh
Carregando www.goooooooogle.com.br (site não existe)
* Rebuilt URL to: www.goooooooogle.com.br/
* Could not resolve host: www.goooooooogle.com.br
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.goooooooogle.com.br
```

## Comando `trap`

O comando `trap` pode ser utilizado junto com o `read` para simular o uso de breakpoints.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "após o comando \"trap 'read' DEBUG\", aperte ENTER para executar o proximo comando"

trap 'read' DEBUG 

echo "olá"
echo "mundo"
echo "bash"
echo "é só love"

trap - DEBUG 

echo "agora"
echo "sem"
echo "debug"
```

$
Execução:

```
$./exemploTrap.sh 
após o comando "trap 'read' DEBUG", aperte ENTER para executar o proximo comando
<ENTER>
olá
<ENTER>
mundo
<ENTER>
bash
<ENTER>
é só love
<ENTER>
agora
sem
debug
$
```

## Fonte

- [Shell Script Profissional - Cap 5 (Debug) - Em Portugûes](http://shellscript.com.br/)
- [TLDP (BASH) - The Linux Documentation Project (Inglês)](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/debugging.html)

Answer (score 4):

Você pode debugar bash executando o script com o parâmetro -x:

```
bash -x nome_do_seu_script.sh
```

Se você só quiser debugar uma parte do código, pode encerrar ela com `set`:

```
set -x
<código>
set +x
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta ajudou muito, eu fazendo umas pesquisas aqui encontrei este [tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/debugging-shell-script.html) que tbm é bem explicado.